# how can I impelement tensorflow.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow.js

I am tryna implement face detection with TensorFlow JavaScript models but when I run this I have a problem the context of the error is:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 22:50-108 export 'SupportedPackages' (imported as 'faceLandmarksDetection') was not found in '@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection' (possible exports: SupportedModels, createDetector, util)
```

I think that is deprecated
and the part of the code that mentions in the error is :

```
  const runFacemesh = async () => {
    const net = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
      faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
    );
```

and you can access to the code with the links I put below:

> https://github.com/mohamad-sw/facemesh

Answer (score 0):

instead of the .load() function use

```
const detectorConfig = {
  runtime: 'tfjs',
  solutionPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh',
}
model = await faceLandmarksDetection.createDetector(faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedModels.MediaPipeFaceMesh, detectorConfig);
```